# PowerBi calculated measures are not effected by categories

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am new to powerBI and i have created a measure using two tables as given below.

```
Paid Users = 
VAR current_month = MAX('Date'[Dates])
VAR customers = CALCULATE(sum('users'[CustomersOrNot]), FILTER(ALL('users'),'users'[CustomersOrNotDate] <= current_month && 'users'[CanceledDate] > current_month && 'users'[category] IN {"001","002","003"}))
return customers
```

so we have users table and Date table but when i try to create a chart of paid Users with category i am getting same values for all the categories instead of different values for different categories.
Users Table
[image]
Dates
[image]

Comment: Sample data and desired output would be helpful

Comment: You are using the `FILTER(ALL(...)...)` syntax which removes all the filters on the users table and later on introduce a filter on users by category in 001, 002, 003. Remove the ALL() and you should get your result: `ALCULATE(sum('users'[CustomersOrNot]), FILTER('users',......`

Comment: @FabianSchenker By removing ALL from the Filter i am getting quite different numbers that does not make sense.

Comment: in that case, we would need more information about your data model and as described by cr7sms sample data and desired output.

Comment: @CR7SMS my date table is quite simple like date, year, month etc and for the other i am updating the question.

Comment: @FabianSchenker  updated the question.

Comment: From what I see, the explanation I gave you should provide you with the correct answer. The issue is, that your cancellation date is BLANK and therefor users that do not have a cancellation date are not counted. Could you replace the blank with today + 1?

Answer (score 1):

In the calculation you are using Filter All which is creating issues. To work around this you can create a column with the following calculation:

```
Paid Users = 
VAR current_month = MAX('Date'[Dates])
VAR customers = CALCULATE(sum(users[CustomerOrNot]), FILTER(ALLEXCEPT('users',users[category]),'users'[CustomerOrNotDate] <= current_month && users[CanceledDate] > current_month && users[category] IN {"001","002","003"}))
return customers
```

You can now aggregate this using `min(Paid Users)`to get the results at a category level. Hope this helps.

Comment: no i need per category count for all categories and this is not working for that just implemented your solution.

Comment: Is the category same as planid in the sample data?

Comment: its same i just forgot to change it.

Comment: Can you post a snapshot of what the created column "Paid Users" looks like in the data? It's working fine with the sample data I created.

Comment: i think there is a filter on users table so when i remove all and it gives me different results but i resolved it by creating separate table with fields of interest only and apply measures on that table.